# Drupal menu items and blog entries disappeared for anonymous users

Tags: linux, drupal, drupal-6, blogs, menuitem

I've been struggling with a problem now for a few hour and I cannot find any answers or anyone with the same problem -

Some menu items are missing on my site www.namhost.com (Drupal 6.22) and when viewing the blog it shows "No blog entries have been created". When I log in as admin everything works fine, so this problem only occurs for anonymous/guest users.

I've changed nothing on the site which may have caused this problem and here comes the really strange part - When viewing a copy of the site locally everything works 100% even for anonymous/guest users.

I've tried:

- flushing caches
- rebuilding permissions
- checked if the "anonymous" user is present in the database
- viewing on different browsers

None of these yielded any results.

Because the problem doesn't occur locally I'm starting to believe this could be a problem on the server the site is hosted on (Linux with PHP5.2), but the admins had a look and couldn't find anything.

Any help/insight would be highly appreciated.

================FIXED<<<<<<<-----------------------------

I am not allowed to answer my own question and it was suggested that I edit the question to include my answer so here goes:

Firstly, thanks for all the responses.

I disabled the "ACL" module (http://drupal.org/project/acl) and the problem was solved. It was previously used for our forum which was also disabled a few months back, so it's not needed any more.

I still have no idea why this module caused the site to work locally but not on the server. I will be in contact with the server admins to find out if they changed/updated anything on the server which may have caused this module to cause a malfunction.

Any insight could still be helpful top prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

### Check your Drupal config:

Are you using node_access, content_access, or any other permissions-related addon mods? Disable them and see if the problem persists. If that doesn't work, disable all non-core mods and re-enable them one-at-a-time until you find the offender.

### Compare your hosting configs:

If it's not related to Drupal, compare the local and remote server configurations. Do both use the same versions of php, apache, apc, cgi, etc.? A `phpinfo();` on both servers should give you the most important details for comparison. Do a similar comparison of the MySQL setup and content. Finally, check for differences in your .htaccess files (if any) between the two locations.

### Test another hosting enviornment:

Download a virtual appliance like QuickStart which is already configured to host Drupal sites for development and non-production purposes, and see if the site works correctly in that. If it does, you could do an additional validation by porting to a new host who offers a trial/money-back-guarantee and see if it works correctly there.

If your site works fine elsewhere, give your current host a good thrashing for making you go through all of this to figure out the problem lies on their end.